# MongoDB/Rails: Storing Edits in Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Using rails/mongodb, what is the best way to store edit dates? I don't care about what was edited, but I do care about the date it was edited.

A better model would be the library book example:

A single book is checked out and checked in many times--I simply want to store the check out date and check in date.

Is it possible to do this in a single array in one collection, or should I make a separate collection for "checkouts" and an entry (or book" has many "checkouts")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the book example you gave, if you don't plan on having thousands of checkouts, I think the best way is to have an embedded collection of Checkouts (with a date and whatever fields you want) in the Books collection.

But you have to keep in mind that each time you will load a Book, all its Checkouts will be loaded too. Basically it's great if you often need the dates when fetching a book but if it is rare you may not want to do this.

```
class Book
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    embeds_many :checkouts

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :checkouts, :allow_destroy => true

    field :book_name, :type => String

    attr_accessible :book_name
end

class Checkout
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    embedded_in :book, inverse_of: :checkouts
end
```

Comment: So, perhaps in preparation for the future...a book will have a lot of checkouts in a year's time...it would probably be more efficient to store those in a separate class/collection?

Comment: Well you need to know 2 things to make the right call: the maximum size of a document (including its embedded children) is 16MB. Besides, storing the checkouts in a separate collection forces MongoDB executing 2 requests when fetching the checkouts for a book: get the book THEN get all the checkouts with, say, a book_id of mybook.id (for instance) cause there is no "join" in MongoDB. If you think none of your books and there checkouts (1 book and all its checkout for instance) would never exceed 16MB then embedding is definitely more efficient: only 1 query to load all the books and checkouts.

Comment: Sparda, this is very helpful.  Can you expand on the answer? I'm having trouble getting this to work with my view/controller...how do I render the fields in "checkout"? Or how do I, with the initial creation of a book have a default "check_in" date?

Comment: Or a better way to ask: Do I have to make separate .rb files? books.rb, checkouts.rb, their controllers, and views separately?

Comment: I edited my answer, not really sure to understand what you asked for but I hope it helps. I use Mongoid, and this is basically how you set fields, declare the model as a Mongoid model and make the parent model accept nested attributes for the child model (regarding your question: how to render fields for checkouts).

Comment: regarding your other question, books.rb and checkouts.rb: yes. For the reste, I guess you will only have a BookController and its views, unless you happen to manage checkouts independently from books.

Comment: Great. One more thing: How do I access the nested attributes in an embedded document? I'm calling books.checkouts.date instead of books.checkout_date...but getting a "method not found" error. How do I format the BSON of the nested attributes in MONGOHQ? :)

Comment: If you want to access the attributes of a checkout it's as usual: my_book.checkouts.first.date, my_book.checkouts returns an array of checkouts so you cannot call .date on it.

Comment: Very good. One last question, and I should be good...
So, on creation of an entry, I need to add a "date_due" in the embedded document to keep from getting a nil on my "show" view...how do I render embedded document fields in the parent "new" view/controller?

Comment: If you only submit a checkout in the new then in your controller you can do smthg like: *@checkout = Checkout.new* and then in your view *<%= form_for @checkout do |f| %><%= hidden_field_tag 'book_id', my_book.id %><%= f.datetime :due_date %><%= f.submit 'OK'>* (not sure about the f.datetime) and then do what you have to with the params of the checkout and 'params[:book_id]' in the checkout's controller create method. If you submit both a new book and one or more checkouts at the same time, then I suggest reading a bit of "nested forms" here http://goo.gl/SO0CJ